# Do I Need a Second Router?

Tags: networking, router

I am foolishly new to this. I am setting up a home server for access through the internet when I am away from home. There is an ethernet jack behind it. I am told not to connect a computer directly to the internet without a router due to security reasons. Now, my landlord has a router running in the basement for us.

I can think of two scenarios. The first is that the ethernet jack is somehow connected to the router downstairs. In that instance, I probably wouldn't need a router, right? The other scenario is that the jack is connected right to the internet. In that case, I would have to connect a router in between my computer and the port. If that's so, what are the options so that I don't interfere with my landlord's router?

Comment: In order to answer this question you need to determine what the port is connected to exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet doesn't come to your house via an Ethernet cable, so you need some piece inbetween anyway. This is normally your cable modem, and they come with routers (separate or in one device) to enable multiple devices in your house to connect at the same time. So a router is needed - but only *one* router.

You can connect your server to the router in the basement via an Ethernet cable, or - probably much easier - via wireless connection. The lower speed of wireless versus LAN is irrelevant, as the internet access you have will be slower than the wireless anyway.

If wireless is not strong enough, or your server doesn't have a card, or you cannot connect to that router via a cable (because of distance, holes in the ceiling, etc.), you can buy a second router and use it as 'access point' - most routers can be configured as that. This second router will connect to the one in the basement, and will sit near your server. You can again connect it to your server via an ethernet cable or wireless.

Comment: I'd like the computer to be wired to the internet for a more consistent signal.  And, it is impossible for me to hook it up directly the existing router.  So, I'd like to run a wire from the ethernet jack through a second router to my computer, if that's possible.  Do you have any suggestions for a router that plays well with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it sounds like you have already connected to your landlord's router from your personal computer (not the server you are trying to setup.) If this is not the case, then I'd first connect as a regular user to make sure you can get to the basement router and test out the signal strength and stability before dealing with the server.

Then, for the server; I'd recommend using a cable to the basement router for a more stable connection. Depending on where you are in the building, the wireless signal could fluctuate and if you're hopping through the Internet -> the basement router -> your access point/your server you may find your remote connection drops unexpectedly.

Comment: I cannot wire the computer directly to the router in the basement.  What happens if I connect a second router up to the wall jack and then wire that directly to my server?

Answer (score 2):

The primary role of a router is to connect one network to another - ie a home network to the internet.  Domestic routers also have basic firewalls in them which provide protection against those who are not part of your network gaining access to your network.  In simple terms, the people and devices you don't trust are on one side of the firewall (the outside), and the people and devices you do trust are on the other (the inside).

Your description of the setup is that your building has a shared router provided by your landlord.  So consider the trust model - you are on the inside - who else is on the inside?  Do you trust them?  If not, then a router at your perimeter will provide separation between you and them.